# "Container preempted by scheduler" error for Oozie launcher does not cause Oozie action to fail

Tags: hadoop, oozie

My Oozie workflow has a Java action. If the Oozie launcher task for that action is killed due to "Container preempted by scheduler" for example, another Oozie launcher task will be attempted. The desired behavior is: if an Oozie launcher task is killed or fails, fail the action. How can I configure this in Oozie?

Answer (score 0):

`<global>
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.maxattempts</name>
        <value>1</value>
      </property>
      </configuration>
    </global>`